# Arriving in Dubai Terminal 3, departing from Terminal 2, but need lounge access in Terminal 3

Tags: dubai, emirates, airport-terminals, flydubai

I have booked a ticket with Emirates from New York to Kilimanjaro (Tanzania). The first flight is from New York to Dubai Terminal 3, and the second flight is a codeshare with FlyDubai from Terminal 2 to Kilimanjaro.

I have 6 hours between the two flights and would like to spend the time in the Emirates lounge in Terminal 3.

Do I need to transfer to Terminal 2 as soon as I arrive or is it possible to enter Terminal 3 to spend time in the Emirates lounge? Will I have access to the Emirates buses that transport passengers to the gates in Terminal 2 from the departure area in Terminal 3?

Answer (score 2):

The Emirates Business and Marhaba lounges in Terminal 3 arrivals (level 1) are available to its arriving and departing passengers. Arrival hall signage points to where to get the shuttle bus that runs between Terminals 2 and 3.

> **[Emirates Lounges](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/emirates-terminal-3/facilities.aspx)**
>
> Before takeoff or after landing, Emirates passengers can relax, refresh, and prepare for the next step in their travels in one of our exclusive airport lounges. Emirates First Class and Business Class Lounges feature luxurious comfort and five-star service, while our marhaba lounge—available to Emirates passengers travelling in every class of service—captures the ambience of traditional Arabia.
>
> [**Transferring to or from Emirates Terminal 3**](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/emirates-terminal-3/finding-your-way.aspx)
>
> For your convenience there are buggies to transport you within the terminal buildings, but not between the terminals.
>
> If you are transferring from an Emirates flight to a flydubai flight, you have to use a dedicated bus service to the F Gates in Terminal 2. This bus ride can take up to 40 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be allowed access in Terminal 3 lounge as your flight will depart from Terminal 2.
I have faced same scenario at Frankfurt airport and lounge access was denied as flight departure was from different terminal.

As i understand Lounges are waiting areas for Departures for people of same terminal.

Comment: I was able to use the lounge in Terminal 3 and then take a bus to the F Gates in Terminal 2